# Segmentation fault on using Intel C Compiler on Linux with libstdc++

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, libstdc++, icc

I have installed Intel Composer 2013 and trying to build the most simple C++ application

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
}
```

with

```
$ icc -v
  icc version 12.1.2 (gcc version 4.7.0 compatibility)
```

After starting the program I get a segmentation fault:

```
(gdb) run
    Starting program: /home/paceholder/work/test/test 

    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    0x00007ffff7911bb1 in std::ostream::sentry::sentry(std::ostream&) () from 
    /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.4.183/bin/sourcechecker/lib/intel64/pinruntime
    /libstdc++.so.6

    Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install 
    glibc-2.14.1-14.12.5.x86_64 intel-sourcechecker-common-183-13.1-4.noarch

(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007ffff7911bb1 in std::ostream::sentry::sentry(std::ostream&) () 
    from /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.4.183/bin/sourcechecker/lib/intel64/pinruntime
    /libstdc++.so.6

#1  0x00007ffff79134a6 in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&
std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long) () 
from /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.4.183/bin/sourcechecker/lib/intel64/pinruntime/libstdc++.so.6

#2  0x00007ffff791379f in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&
std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) ()
from /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.4.183/bin/sourcechecker/lib/intel64/pinruntime/libstdc++.so.6

#3  0x0000000000400987 in main ()
```

ldd gives:

```
 $ ldd ./test
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff1f52f000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f514de01000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.4.183/bin/sourcechecker/lib/intel64/pinruntime/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f514daf5000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.4.183/bin/sourcechecker/lib/intel64/pinruntime/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f514d8dd000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f514d54e000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f514d34a000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f514e058000)
```

The system used CentOS 6.4, 64 bit

What could be a reason for such an error and how I can fix it?

Comment: Seg fault comes from trying to access memory that's inaccessible to the datatype/program itself.  If you built it successfully and you get this error when you RUN it, check the permissions of the output program, make sure it has +x.

Comment: In case I have no permissions Linux would not allow me to start the program.

In my case it starts and then on the line where I use `std::cout` it falls.
I do have +x for it.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a product compatibility issue. Have you checked the release notes to see if the Intel compiler release is supported on CentOS 6.4? I looked at compiler version 13.x release notes and the supported RHEL version is 4! You may also want to try installing latest updates for the product from Intel and post on Intel software support forums.

Comment: The funny thing is that I use libstdc++ from Intel Compiler's distribution. I pointed it out with `ldd ./test` output.

Now I am trying to understand if CentOS version can affect the compatibility.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too, but replacement stdc++ still interacts with various other system libs - like libc and the system linker - so there is always a chance something will go wrong! (I also speak based on previous experience with Intel compiler, btw :))

Comment: After the downgrade to GCC 4.4 (standard to CentOS 6.4) I do not reproduce this error anymore